# How Can I run an iOS application,`i.e. *ipa`, on my Macbook pro (OSX)?

Tags: iphone, macos, ipa

I need to install an application which is only available for ipads and iphones on my Macbook pro. But,  I don't have an iphone or ipad. So my question is:
How Can I run an iOS application,`i.e. *ipa`, on my Macbook pro (OSX)?
Is there any online simulator that I can use for that purpose

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

OS X runs on Intel CPUs. iPhone apps run on ARM CPUs. The Simulator that comes with Xcode runs x86 code -- it's not an emulator like the Android developer kit.

Comment: oh really, That's so disappointing :( . Is there any online simulator that I can use for that purpose? @stephen-darlington